# Boto3 CloudWatch - put_metric_alarm with multiple metrics and a math expression

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create an alarm with Boto3 - CloudWatch - put_metric_alarm and having difficulties.

Here are the keyword arguments being supplied to the function:

```
{'ActionsEnabled': False,
 'AlarmDescription': 'Monitor for Idle instances',
 'AlarmName': 'IdleComponents',
 'ComparisonOperator': 'GreaterThanThreshold',
 'DatapointsToAlarm': 6,
 'EvaluationPeriods': 6,
 'Metrics': [{'Id': 'CPU',
              'MetricStat': {'Metric': {'Dimensions': [{'Name': 'InstanceId',
                                                        'Value': 'i-XX'}],
                                        'MetricName': 'CPUUtilization',
                                        'Namespace': 'AWS/EC2'},
                             'Period': 300,
                             'Stat': 'Average',
                             'Unit': 'Percent'},
              'ReturnData': False},
             {'Id': 'Net',
              'MetricStat': {'Metric': {'Dimensions': [{'Name': 'InstanceId',
                                                        'Value': 'i-XX'}],
                                        'MetricName': 'NetworkIn',
                                        'Namespace': 'AWS/EC2'},
                             'Period': 300,
                             'Stat': 'Average',
                             'Unit': 'Megabytes'},
              'ReturnData': False},
             {'Expression': 'IF(CPU < 5, 1, 0) AND IF(Net < 5, 1, 0)',
              'Id': 'e1',
              'ReturnData': True}],
 'Threshold': 0}
```

From visual inspection this appears to be a valid input, and the expression works as desired when creating it manually on the CloudWatch console, but when running this through Boto3 I get:

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the PutMetricAlarm operation: Invalid metrics list

The documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.put_metric_alarm), claims that you may define an alarm such that you may use up to 10 metrics and 10 expressions, with one of the Metric queries returning data for the alarm.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Id must start with a lower case letter, try changing `CPU` and `Net` to `cpu` and `net`.

Comment: Yikes this was the case.  Thanks for pointing this out.  The documentation mentions this on the last sentence of the Id field - "The valid characters are letters, numbers, and underscore. The first character must be a lowercase letter."

Would be nice if the input validation error clarified this.